# return empty using for loop on restful api's is not working

Tags: python, sql, api, flask

```
infos = []
    if ex:
        for info in ex:
            info = {
                "ex":timezone_iso(info['ex'])
            }
            infos.append(info)
        return infos
```

> i want to return more than one data in array but the for loop is not working as it is since it returns empty. is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What is `ex`? Can you [edit] your question and make it a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 0):

create infos variable outside of for loop
like this

```
infos = []
for .....:
   info = {}
   infos.append(info)
```